# DNS server doesn't get data python

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, dns

i built a simple DNS server.. and i'm just trying to print the data (the whole packet) but my server stuck at the recvfrom part.

i tried to open a file that i got as adminstor which changes my DNS server to 127.0.0.1 but it doesn't work.

this is my code:
i tried to write some url's on my browser but my server doesn't get nothing and stuck at the recv.

```
import socket
myserver = sokcet.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCKET_DGRAM)
myserver.bind(('0.0.0.0',53))
data, addr = myserver.recvfrom(1024)
print data
```

Comment: `sokcet -> socket`

Comment: yes i just see it now. this was just a typing mistake here (my code was right).  BTW i fixed the problem.. apperantly this file didn't changed my defult DNS's server ip... now it's work